# Where is the controller in the MVVM pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, mvvm

I was looking for differences between the MVVM and MVC pattern. The MVC pattern has a controller that checks if what page it needs to show. Where is that check in the MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding in MVC usage. MVC is only used to handle single page. In order to find the proper page to render, other patterns like Page Controller or Application Controller shall be used.

For smaller applications, you can use navigation in controllers themselves.
In MVVM you can apply the logic in ViewModel as you have applied in Controller, or use Application Controller instead